# Using an Nvidia card instead of Intel graphics on Fedora

Tags: linux, graphics-card, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have used the integrated Intel graphics for a while on my Fedora 24 machine and now installed an Nvidia card that I want to use instead. I have already disabled the integrated graphics in the BIOS and the controller isn't listed anymore when I run `lspci -v | grep VGA`:

```
[christian ~]% lspci -v | grep VGA
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

However, there is something wrong because the resolution is only 1024x768 and all UI effects (animations, …) are disabled. The details tab in the system settings shows `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)` as the graphics driver. I think this line didn't change after I switched the graphics card, so maybe there is something wrong with the driver.

**What do I have to do to get Full HD resolution and faster graphics?** I don't want to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say
**What do I have to do to get Full HD resolution and faster graphics?**
And then you say
**I don't want to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers.**

Which is it? ;)

Seriously, the best way to take full advantage of your NVidia graphics card is to use the proprietary drivers.  This is actually relatively painless; if you use the rpmfusion repos, you can get the NVidia proprietary drivers as rpms via yum, and keep current on them as updates become available.
See **https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/** for information on using RPM Fusion repos; you'll want `rpmfusion-free`, `rpmfusion-free-updates`, `rpmfusion-nonfree`, and `rpmfusion-nonfree-updates`.

Aside from that, the non-proprietary driver you would want to use for NVidia display adapters is called `nouveau`.  You should see it in `lsmod`, unless you have it disabled somehow (you may want to look for stuff in /etc/modprobe.d and friends that blacklists `nouveau` as this is fairly common).  You might also just see if you can

> `modprobe nouveau`

and see if there's anything wrong with the kernel module preventing you from using it.  Of course you also need the `xorg-x11-drv-nouveau` rpm installed as well to be able to use it with X.

---

(Not that it matters, but I've been using exclusively nvidia adapters with the nvidia proprietary drivers since something like Fedora 16. I understand the reticence to use proprietary stuff, but this is one case where I was perfectly happy to dispense with my principles once I saw the difference the proprietary stuff made, and how much more linux-friendly NVidia is than, say, Radeon. Not to say that NVidia is open, but at least their stuff works well and they provide current, uncrippled drivers for Linux users.  If you have the freedom to try them, I'd encourage at least giving the proprietary stuff a quick test drive. But do yourself a huge favor, use the rpmfusion packages and not nvidia's clunky installer.  It's *much* easier to maintain if you keep it, and ***much*** easier to remove if you don't.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that the drivers can be installed from RPM Fusion. I have tried (and failed) to install them manually in the past and didn't want to do that again. :D Now it's working perfectly.